# how to capture HID hex button codes for usb gamepad

Tags: usb, hid, firmware, descriptor, gamepad

Hi I have some firmware I want to modify that reads from USB gamepads, I want to edit the firmware for my own gamepad

I assume these hex codes refer to up down left right and buttons on the gamepad, this gamepad is a cheap
nonbranded one detected as a Dragon rise chip in windows

0x11,0x40,0x21,0xC0,0x10,0x40,0x20,0xC0,0x36,0xFF

I need to find the correct set of 10 hex codes for a different Logitech USB gamepad, is there an easy way to find this in windows?

I have tried using hid capture program but the hex dump has lots of sets of hex codes and I don't know how to identify the buttons or directions

Answer (score 1):

You need to [get the report descriptor](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-hid-bugs/) and [parse it](https://eleccelerator.com/usbdescreqparser/) to understand how button and axis values are represented in the input report. The report descriptor format is documented in the [Device Class Definition for HID](https://www.usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111).

D-pad inputs are almost always represented as a rotational axis. I have a Logitech F310 and it represents the D-pad as a 4-bit value in the lower bits of the 5th byte:

```
80 7F 80 7F 00 00 00 FF  // Holding up
80 7F 80 7F 01 00 00 FF  // Holding up + right
80 7F 80 7F 02 00 00 FF  // Holding right
80 7F 80 7F 03 00 00 FF  // Holding down + right
80 7F 80 7F 04 00 00 FF  // Holding down
80 7F 80 7F 05 00 00 FF  // Holding down + left
80 7F 80 7F 06 00 00 FF  // Holding left
80 7F 80 7F 07 00 00 FF  // Holding up + left
80 7F 80 7F 08 00 00 FF  // Not holding any direction
```

Note how the value increases as we move clockwise around the D-pad. There's a special value for the "not holding any direction" state.